# Iterate over large external postgres db, manipulate rows, write output to rails postgres db

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I've got a postgres DB with around 200,000,000 rows and 6 columns.  The columns have int, date, and string, but no primary key and no unique values on which to base a primary key.

The records in this DB contain the raw data I need for one of my rails postgres models.  I'd like to iterate through the full external DB, perform a calculation on each row of it, and then write the output to my rails model.

I've got no issue connecting to the DB or accessing records through ActiveRecord, but everything I try for iterating over the DB is failing or taking far too long.  I've tried the following:

- ExternalDB.all.each
- ExternalDB.find_all.each
- Adding an "id" column to ExternalDB using [these instructions](http://www.kindle-maps.com/blog/retrospectivly-adding-a-unique-primary-id-column-to-a-table-in-postgresql.html)

I think the answer will be to do the iterations using SQL, but I'm not even sure how to start on that.

Comment: I voted up just for the 200m rows! What kind of data is in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use a cursor, either a protocol-level one or [an SQL-level cursor with `DECLARE` and `FETCH`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-declare.html).

Handily, [someone already wrote an ActiveRecord adapter for PostgreSQL cursors](https://github.com/afair/postgresql_cursor); see [rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/postgresql_cursor).

You might also find this question informative: [Are there any Ruby ORMs which use cursors or smart fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8849340/398670)

I haven't checked the source code / docs to see if the Pg gem supports PostgreSQL's protocol-level cursors for batched reads, but if there's already a tool to do it (as linked above) it's probably not worth exploring.

Comment: using the cursor gem you provided - works great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From a *Postgres* perspective:

You don't need to have unique values in order to have an *index*. (There are *unique indexes*, to be sure, which is what having a *primary key* enforces, but that isn't required.)

The first thing would be to have an *index* containing the search terms that you will be using. If you're going to be searching on all 6 of the values you mentioned, then you should try creating an *index* on those 6 values.

Depending on the exact nature of your query, it doesn't necessarily guarantee that that index will be used, however. It will depend in part on how many rows the *query planner* thinks will be returned by the query, which will in turn determine whether it tries to use the *index* for the scan or if it goes to do a *sequential scan*.

So, once you create that index, try in *psql* or *PgAdmin* a `SELECT` that you would want to use, and run an `EXPLAIN` on it to see if the query planner is planning to use the *index* or not, and then run it to see how it performs.

If it performs well then you can integrate it back into your *Rails* code, probably via raw *SQL*.

Comment: I think this will probably be the best approach as we scale this import task.  For now it's probably a bit more than we need, upvoted for the great explanation though.  Thanks!